# Custom speech service- Execption (Getting exeception while test failed with login failed, Transport error)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Followed the below steps

1. Build the custom speech service -(https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Custom-Speech-Service).
2. After build the custom speech service, Used the ( https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows) sample code for testing the custom speech model. While testing got the exception as Failed with Login error detail message as "Transport error".

Is there a way to test the custom speech model in a windows app?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [new speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/) which works with the custome speech service. You can find samples for using custom speech service [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L108). You can also use the new speech SDK in UWP (see [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-csharp-uwp)).

Thanks,

Comment: Followed the sdk sample application. While using bing speech service by default taking location as global. It is not allowing me to change the location to "west us or east Us" below is the parameter detail

Comment: var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("4c1e0fcdd9f149b4acf5cad514c7cxxx", "global");

Comment: Got the below exception Reason: WebSocket Upgrade failed with an authentication error (401). Please check the subscription key or the authorization token, and the region name.

Comment: While using custom speech model I got the below exception Again I'm getting an error as given below. Reason: WebSocket Upgrade failed with an authentication error (403). Please check the subscription key or the authorization token, and the region name.

Comment: You need to specify service region, e.g. westus, eastasia, when creating speech factory. This is to make sure that the data you sent to the service is bound to the region you choose.Currently, "global" is not supported. Please note that your subscription key is also bound to a specific region, which should match the region you specified.

Comment: For using custom speech model, please make sure that the model id specified is deployed to the subscription associated with the subscription key.